# How to clear only plots in pyqt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created a GUI that shows 6 plots in canvas importing multiple files but I would like to make one button to clear only plots (Data graph) to redraw plot next time. I already made "Clear" Button but it doesn't work properly. How can I do with this?

***read me: This program has been made only to be asked here. So when you run this code, just click "importing file and plot" button and select any files that you have and the multiple files you choose are used only for making name of the legend in plot and the data for plot is already in my code to generate plot.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QSpinBox, QLabel, 
QVBoxLayout, QFileDialog, QApplication, QRadioButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets as mwg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from math import log10
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUI()
        self.f_range = '2'
        self.l_range = '3'
    def setupUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 50, 1500, 950)
        self.setWindowTitle("Material Properties Viewer v1.0")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))
        self.lable = QLabel("Select the Temperature", self)
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox(self)
        self.spinBox.setValue(40)
        self.spinBox.setSingleStep(10)
        self.spinBox.setMinimum(-30)
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(100)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.spinBoxChanged)
        self.VIS_Button = QPushButton("Importing File and Plot")
        self.CL_Button = QPushButton("Clear All")
        self.Plabel = QLabel("Select the Frequency ", self)
        self.radio1 = QRadioButton('200- 1000 Hz')
        self.radio1.clicked.connect(self.radioButtonClicked)
        self.radio2 = QRadioButton('200- 20000 Hz')
        self.radio2.clicked.connect(self.radioButtonClicked)
        self.radio3 = QRadioButton('10000- 20000 Hz')
        self.radio3.clicked.connect(self.radioButtonClicked)
        self.radio1.setChecked(True)
        self.VIS_Button.clicked.connect(self.VIS_ANALYSIS)
        self.CL_Button.clicked.connect(self.Clear)
        self.fig = plt.Figure()
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(231, position=[0.045, 0.55, 0.275, 0.4])  
        self.ax1.set_title('Modulus1')
        self.ax1.set_xlabel('Frequency')
        self.ax1.set_ylabel('Modulus')
        self.ax2 = self.fig.add_subplot(232, position=[0.375, 0.55, 0.275, 0.4]) 
        self.ax2.set_title('Modulus2')
        self.ax2.set_xlabel('Frequency')
        self.ax2.set_ylabel('Modulus')
        self.ax3 = self.fig.add_subplot(233, position=[0.7, 0.55, 0.275, 0.4]) 
        self.ax3.set_title('Modulus3')
        self.ax3.set_xlabel('Frequency')
        self.ax3.set_ylabel('Modulus')
        self.ax4 = self.fig.add_subplot(234, position=[0.045, 0.06, 0.275, 0.4])
        self.ax4.set_title('Modulus4')
        self.ax4.set_xlabel('Frequency')
        self.ax4.set_ylabel('Modulus')
        self.ax5 = self.fig.add_subplot(235, position=[0.375, 0.06, 0.275, 0.4])
        self.ax5.set_title('Modulus5')
        self.ax5.set_xlabel('Frequency')
        self.ax5.set_ylabel('Modulus')
        self.ax6 = self.fig.add_subplot(236, position=[0.7, 0.06, 0.275, 0.4])
        self.ax6.set_title('Modulus6')
        self.ax6.set_xlabel('Frequency')
        self.ax6.set_ylabel('Modulus')
        self.ax1.grid(True)
        self.ax2.grid(True)
        self.ax3.grid(True)
        self.ax4.grid(True)
        self.ax5.grid(True)
        self.ax6.grid(True)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        leftLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        leftLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        rightLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        rightLayout.addWidget(self.lable)
        rightLayout.addWidget(self.spinBox)
        rightLayout.addWidget(self.Plabel)
        rightLayout.addWidget(self.radio1)
        rightLayout.addWidget(self.radio2)
        rightLayout.addWidget(self.radio3)
        rightLayout.addWidget(self.VIS_Button)
        rightLayout.addWidget(self.CL_Button)
        rightLayout.addStretch(1)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(leftLayout)
        layout.addLayout(rightLayout)
        layout.setStretchFactor(leftLayout, 1)
        layout.setStretchFactor(rightLayout, 0)
        self.setLayout(layout)
    def Clear(self):
        self.fig.axes.clear()
    def spinBoxChanged(self):
        self.spinBox.value()
    def radioButtonClicked(self):
        if self.radio1.isChecked():
            self.f_range = "2"  # 200 - 1000
            self.l_range = "3"
        elif self.radio2.isChecked():
            self.f_range = "2"  # 200 - 20000
            self.l_range = "4.5"
        elif self.radio3.isChecked():
            self.f_range = "4"
            self.l_range = "4.5"
    def VIS_ANALYSIS(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self)
        filename = list(fname[0])
        for i in range(len(filename)):
            lable_name = filename[i].split('/')[-1][:-4]
            self.ax1.plot([0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], label=lable_name)
            self.ax1.legend(loc="upper right")
            self.ax2.plot([0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], label=lable_name)
            self.ax2.legend(loc="upper right")
            self.ax3.plot([0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], label=lable_name)
            self.ax3.legend(loc="upper right")
            self.ax4.plot([0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], label=lable_name)
            self.ax4.legend(loc="upper right")
            self.ax5.plot([0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], label=lable_name)
            self.ax5.legend(loc="upper right")
            self.ax6.plot([0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], label=lable_name)
            self.ax6.legend(loc="upper right")
            self.canvas.draw()
    def PYN_ANALYSIS(self):
        QMessageBox.about(self, "Warning", "It is not available yet..!")
    def closeEvent(self, QCloseEvent):
        ans = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Confirm Close', 'Are you sure you want to close?',
                                   QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        if ans == QMessageBox.Yes:
            QCloseEvent.accept()
        else:
            QCloseEvent.ignore()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWidget()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DizietAsahi answer works, you need to update the canvas

```
...
def Clear(self):
    # self.fig.axes.clear()

    for ax in self.fig.axes:
        ax.clear()

    self.ax1.set_title('Modulus1')
    self.ax1.set_xlabel('Frequency')
    self.ax1.set_ylabel('Modulus')
    self.ax2.set_title('Modulus2')
    self.ax2.set_xlabel('Frequency')
    self.ax2.set_ylabel('Modulus')
    self.ax3.set_title('Modulus3')
    self.ax3.set_xlabel('Frequency')
    self.ax3.set_ylabel('Modulus')
    self.ax4.set_title('Modulus4')
    self.ax4.set_xlabel('Frequency')
    self.ax4.set_ylabel('Modulus')
    self.ax5.set_title('Modulus5')
    self.ax5.set_xlabel('Frequency')
    self.ax5.set_ylabel('Modulus')
    self.ax6.set_title('Modulus6')
    self.ax6.set_xlabel('Frequency')
    self.ax6.set_ylabel('Modulus')

    self.ax1.grid(True)
    self.ax2.grid(True)
    self.ax3.grid(True)
    self.ax4.grid(True)
    self.ax5.grid(True)
    self.ax6.grid(True)            

    # refresh canvas            
    self.canvas.draw()                       # +++

...
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped me a lot !! :)

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
def Clear(self):
    self.fig.axes.clear()
```

is incorrect, since `fig.axes` is a list of axes, and does not have a `clear()` function.

You need to do

```
def Clear(self):
    for ax in self.fig.axes:
        ax.clear()
```

Comment: could you please run and make sure ?